# Is there a way to loop through an xml file and change specific tags according to how many times that tag comes up?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, beautifulsoup

In my XML file [studentinfo.xml] is there a way to loop through the xml file and change specific tags (and specific child tags) [there will be multiple ones that need to change] and add a number on the end?

**The file is significantly larger

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stu:StudentBreakdown>
<stu:Studentdata>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Sam Davies</st:name>
        <st:age>15</st:age>
        <st:hair>Black</st:hair>
        <st:eyes>Blue</st:eyes>
        <st:grade>10</st:grade>
        <st:teacher>Draco Malfoy</st:teacher>
        <st:dorm>Innovation Hall</st:dorm>
        <st:name>Master Splinter</st:name>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Cassie Stone</st:name>
        <st:age>14</st:age>
        <st:hair>Science</st:hair>
        <st:grade>9</st:grade>
        <st:teacher>Luna Lovegood</st:teacher>
        <st:name>Kelly Clarkson</st:name>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Derek Brandon</st:name>
        <st:age>17</st:age>
        <st:eyes>green</st:eyes>
        <st:teacher>Ron Weasley</st:teacher>
        <st:dorm>Hogtie Manor</st:dorm>
        <st:name>Miley Cyrus</st:name>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
</stu:Studentdata>
</stu:StudentBreakdown>
```

Each tag should be unique for each Student Screening and I want to make them unique by adding a number on the end, see below for desired ouput:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stu:StudentBreakdown>
<stu:Studentdata>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name0>Sam Davies</st:name0>
        <st:age>15</st:age>
        <st:hair>Black</st:hair>
        <st:eyes>Blue</st:eyes>
        <st:grade>10</st:grade>
        <st:teacher>Draco Malfoy</st:teacher>
        <st:dorm>Innovation Hall</st:dorm>
        <st:name1>Master Splinter</st:name1>
        <st:name2>Peter Griffin</st:name2>
        <st:name3>Louis Griffin</st:name3>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name0>Cassie Stone</st:name0>
        <st:age>14</st:age>
        <st:hair>Science</st:hair>
        <st:grade>9</st:grade>
        <st:teacher>Luna Lovegood</st:teacher>
        <st:name1>Kelly Clarkson</st:name1>
        <st:name2>Stewie Griffin</st:name2>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name0>Derek Brandon</st:name0>
        <st:age>17</st:age>
        <st:eyes>green</st:eyes>
        <st:teacher>Ron Weasley</st:teacher>
        <st:dorm>Hogtie Manor</st:dorm>
        <st:name1>Miley Cyrus</st:name1>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
</stu:Studentdata>
</stu:StudentBreakdown>
```

Comment: any particular reason you may not want to put an attribute a single time in the `stu:StudentScreening` node?
e.g.
`<stu:StudentScreening id="123">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bs4, you can assign a new name to Tag simply with `Tag.name = 'NEW_NAME'`, so you just have to enumerate and loop through.

(I pasted your first xml snippet to `xmlStr`.)

```py
xSoup = BeautifulSoup(xmlStr, 'lxml') ## do NOT use 'xml' parser here unless you want to lose namespaces

enumTags = ['st:name', 'stu:studentscreening']
for d in [c for c in xSoup.descendants if c.name]:
    for name in enumTags:
        for i, t in enumerate(d.find_all(name, recursive=False)):
            t.name = f'{t.name}{i}'
```

(You didn't number `studentscreening` in your question, but I wanted to give an example with multiple tags to number; and, setting `recursive=False` reduces redundancies as it restricts `find` to direct children only.)

Now, `print(xSoup)` will give the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html><body><stu:studentbreakdown>
<stu:studentdata>
<stu:studentscreening0>
<st:name0>Sam Davies</st:name0>
<st:age>15</st:age>
<st:hair>Black</st:hair>
<st:eyes>Blue</st:eyes>
<st:grade>10</st:grade>
<st:teacher>Draco Malfoy</st:teacher>
<st:dorm>Innovation Hall</st:dorm>
<st:name1>Master Splinter</st:name1>
</stu:studentscreening0>
<stu:studentscreening1>
<st:name0>Cassie Stone</st:name0>
<st:age>14</st:age>
<st:hair>Science</st:hair>
<st:grade>9</st:grade>
<st:teacher>Luna Lovegood</st:teacher>
<st:name1>Kelly Clarkson</st:name1>
</stu:studentscreening1>
<stu:studentscreening2>
<st:name0>Derek Brandon</st:name0>
<st:age>17</st:age>
<st:eyes>green</st:eyes>
<st:teacher>Ron Weasley</st:teacher>
<st:dorm>Hogtie Manor</st:dorm>
<st:name1>Miley Cyrus</st:name1>
</stu:studentscreening2>
</stu:studentdata>
</stu:studentbreakdown>
</body></html>
```

(You can also save it [to 'x.xml' for example] with `with open('x.xml', 'wb') as f: f.write(xSoup.prettify('utf-8'))`)

Comment: is there a reason why the indents [specifying the child tags] where not used in your answer? Also I didn't number stu:studentscreening because it wasn't giving me a headache lol.

Comment: Is the [c.name] in relation to the [st:name] tag? Also is the d.find_all in regards to finding the tags with ' name ' in it? Im getting an error when trying to use this. Your answer is exactly what I want my output to be, with the exception of the indents being in there as well.

Comment: @Tej About the indent, using `xSoup.prettify()` instead of `str(xSoup)` makes it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bepph.png), but it takes up more space [so I didn't paste it like that in the answer], and I don't know how to control the indent

Comment: @Tej what error are you getting? no, `c.name` doesn't have anything to do with `st:name` specifically. it's just a lazy way of checking if `c` is a Tag [and not a string/comment/etc] since Tags have names [like `st:name` but `st:age` and `body` are *also* Tag names]. Anyways the check is so that `find_all` doesn't give error later, so I guess it would be more appropriate `if callable(getattr(c, 'find_all'))` [instead of `if c.name`] to check that `c` has a `find_all` function .... but I'm curious about your error bc I've never had issue with the lazy method before...

Comment: Hey I got it to work, but its only reading the first occurrence. Do you know how to get it to iterate over the entire xml file ? Would you like an example of what its doing ?

Comment: @Tej yes please [it should be taking care of all occurrences] - could you upload the original file, your code, and the output to drive/pastebin/jsfiddle and share the link?

Comment: I will provide what I can. I apologize for the late reply.

Comment: I have a pastebin, anything would help, https://pastebin.com/u/tjack5

Comment: @Tej I've added edits to your code [ https://pastebin.com/k4XsHCkR - the output links are in comments at the top ]. How were you saving the edited soup btw? It kind of looks like a save from the very first iteration only...

Comment: I didn't get that far [as in saving the edited soup], I wanted to make sure it gave me the desired output first then I would worry about saving the edited soup lol.

Comment: @Tej I see, but it must have printed a crazy amount, so it might have still been better to print the entire soup outside the loop....anyway, does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess Harry Potter has got his magic.

The key idea is to use [XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp).

Python code using lxml lib,

```
import lxml.etree as ET

XSL = '''
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:stu="https://www.example.com/harrypotter" xmlns:st="https://www.example.com/harrypotter">
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="stu:StudentScreening/st:name">
        <xsl:element name="st:name{count(preceding-sibling::st:name)}"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
'''

dom = ET.parse('students.xml')
transform = ET.XSLT(ET.fromstring(XSL))
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom))

newdom.write("out.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

Your input xml file named `students.xml`, which must include namespaces,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stu:StudentBreakdown xmlns:stu="https://www.example.com/harrypotter"  xmlns:st="https://www.example.com/harrypotter">
<stu:Studentdata>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Sam Davies</st:name>
        <st:age>15</st:age>
        <st:hair>Black</st:hair>
        <st:eyes>Blue</st:eyes>
        <st:grade>10</st:grade>
        <st:teacher>Draco Malfoy</st:teacher>
        <st:dorm>Innovation Hall</st:dorm>
        <st:name>Master Splinter</st:name>
        <st:name>Peter Griffin</st:name>
        <st:name>Louis Griffin</st:name>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Cassie Stone</st:name>
        <st:age>14</st:age>
        <st:hair>Science</st:hair>
        <st:grade>9</st:grade>
        <st:teacher>Luna Lovegood</st:teacher>
        <st:name>Kelly Clarkson</st:name>
        <st:name>Stewie Griffin</st:name>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Derek Brandon</st:name>
        <st:age>17</st:age>
        <st:eyes>green</st:eyes>
        <st:teacher>Ron Weasley</st:teacher>
        <st:dorm>Hogtie Manor</st:dorm>
        <st:name>Miley Cyrus</st:name>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
</stu:Studentdata>
</stu:StudentBreakdown>
```

Run the Python code, and you should get a file named `out.xml`.

Comment: Could you explain the need for the XSL ?

Comment: XSLT is a language originally designed for transforming XML documents into other XML documents. One of the benefits of XSLT is that all the processing logic is captured inside the XSL template instead of the python code. For your problem, I thought XSLT was a natural solution as you are dealing with XML files, but I guess the other solution also works. You can read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Comment: the namespaces were a headache, so originally I chose not to use them. The example.com/harrypotter is made up correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's made up and just to pass the XML validation. You could remove the namespaces if that's not required. Then remove the namespaces in XSLT as well and it should still work.